# Import library dependencies in flash (actionscript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am developing quiz application for practice purpose, using Flash CS5.

At the top of my AS3, I have this :

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
```

I use it for load XML file.

I wonder, should I import that library, because it'll compile successfully even I delete that lines?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably placing your code in a frame script, which works with a pseudo `import flash.*.*` scope.

Import statements do not affect performance or file size and are merely an intrinsic to help the compiler understand what you mean when you are referring to `URLLoader`.

As a side note, I highly suggest NOT placing code in frame actions and using a document class object and/or external `.as` files.